# My really old wonder: "defined by" v.s. "defined as"

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases, mathematics

I understand the following sentence:

> The rule was defined as ~~~~ by John.

It can be shortened by omitting "as ~~~~" or "by John", like

> The rule was defined as ~~~~.
>
> The rule was defined by John.

---

Now, my question is what is difference between "defined as" and "defined by" in the context of Mathematical papers or textbooks.

I saw many times they are used interchangeably, e.g.,

> The penalty function is defined by
>
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Equation ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~, (1)
>
> where ~ is ~~~~~~~~~~~~, ~ is ~~~~~~~~~~~, and ~ is ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~. (variable description)

and

> The penalty function is defined as
>
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Equation ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~, (1)
>
> where ~ is ~~~~~~~~~~~~, ~ is ~~~~~~~~~~~, and ~ is ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~. (variable description)

### I guess that both are correct but the meaning is slightly different. What is exactly different???

---

Also, some people write

> where ~ is ~~~~~, ~ is ~~~~~, and ~ is ~~~~~~~.

but the others write

> where ~ is ~~~~~, ~ ~~~~~~, and ~ ~~~~~~~. (Only write the be-verb in the first one.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience,

> **as** is used for a definition, whereas
>   **by** is used for constraints or characteristics

For example,

> The speed of sound is inversely proportional to the **altitude** of an airplane
>
> In the equation, **altitude** is defined **as** the height of an airplane in flight
>
> The possible range or values of altitude are defined **by** the aerodynamics of the airplane.

In particular

> The equation is bounded **by** ...

talks about the limits of the equation, and is usually not described as

> The equation is bounded **as** ...

In your example

> The rule is defined **as** ... **by** John.

Seems to be a mixed metaphor, since the **by** is used to express ownership and not necessarily a property of the rule, unless possibly authorship by John is a determining property.

HTH

Answer (score 2):

In **defined as {X}**

X is the definition.

In **defined by {Y}**

Y can be a person or entity issuing the definition, or it can be a circumstance or quality that is of integral importance to the thing, making it what it is:

> An athlete is defined as a person who engages in a sport.
>
> An athlete is defined by Webster's as "a person who is trained or skilled in exercises, sports, or games requiring physical strength, agility, or stamina".
>
> A world-class athlete is defined by extraordinary skills, strength, and stamina.
>
> Disaster-status is defined by the inability of the stricken community to emerge from the catastrophe without outside help.

Comment: Your answer is concise, so very easily understandable for me. Thank you.